# AmCharts5 values in legend in column chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts5

Here is code example:

https://codepen.io/DenisRoss/pen/rNpgQLv?editors=0010

```js
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {layout: root.verticalLayout}));

var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {minGridDistance: 0});
xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({});

var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
  categoryField: "country",
  renderer: xRenderer,
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
}));


var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: yAxis,
  valueYField: "value",
  categoryXField: "country",
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText:"{valueY}"
  })
}));

series.columns.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});

series.columns.template.adapters.add("stroke", function(stroke, target) {
  return chart.get("colors").getIndex(series.columns.indexOf(target));
});

var data = [{
  country: "A",
  value: 500
}, {
  country: "B",
  value: 300
}, {
  country: "C",
  value: 200
}];

xAxis.data.setAll(data);
series.data.setAll(data);

var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
  nameField: 'categoryX',
  valueField: 'valueY', // WHY DOES NOT WORK? T__T
  centerX: am5.percent(50),
  x: am5.percent(50),
}));
legend.data.setAll(series.dataItems);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

It is AmCharts5 column chart with legend. **But there is no values of columns in legend**.

[image: AmCharts5 column chart]

Here is another code example:

https://codepen.io/DenisRoss/pen/YzYbRrz?editors=0010

```js
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));

var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "categoty",
  legendValueText: "{value}"
}));

series.data.setAll([{
  categoty: "A",
  value: 500
}, {
  categoty: "B",
  value: 300
}, {
  categoty: "C",
  value: 200
}]);

var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
  centerX: am5.percent(50),
  x: am5.percent(50),
}));

legend.data.setAll(series.dataItems);

series.appear(1000, 100);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

It is PieChart with legends **with values in legend**.

[image: AmCharts5 pie chart]

**How can i show values in legend in column chart?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work:
`legend.valueLabels.template.setAll({text: '{valueY}'})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try "legend.data.push(series);"
It has worked at my end....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).